# Undefined index in PHP for a register

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, undefined-index

Im creating a register section within my website, and it seems to be half working.
When the register button is pressed on the next page i receive the message :

> Notice: Undefined index: user_name on line 7, Notice: Undefined index:
>   user_email on line 8, Notice: Undefined index: user_password on line 9

Does anyone know how i can resolve this? please help. This is the code:

```
   Thankyou for registering
   <?php
   include ("dbConnect.php");
   $dbQuery = $db->prepare("select * from loginregister");
   $dbQuery->execute();

   $usernamesignup = $_POST['user_name'];
   $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
   $user_password = $_POST['user_password'];

   $usernamesignup = ($usernamesignup);
   $user_email = ($user_email);
   $user_password = ($user_password);

   $query = "
  INSERT INTO `loginregister`(`id`, `user_name`, `user_email`, `user_password`) VALUES (NULL, '$usernamesignup',
    '$user_email', '$user_password',
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";


  echo "<h2>Thank you for registering!</h2>";



?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Mismatch column name and value in insert query!! ALso post your html form!!

Comment: post your form also.

Comment: See [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12770836#12770836)